# How to count current streak?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of 1s and 0s in excel ranging from **A1:A74** and I am looking to work out what the current streak of 1's is.

For example I have:

```
1
0
1
1
1
```

I would want the streak to give me 3. 
I have tried the following formula which seems to work for smaller ranges, but for my full set it gives me the wrong amount:

`=COUNTA(A1:A73)-MATCH(1,INDEX(1/(A1:A73=0),0))`

Any help would be much appreciated.

edit - I believe i've fixed the formula above to work:

`=COUNTA(S$2:S$74)-MATCH(2, 1/(S2:S$74=0), 1)`

This is basically finding the last position of 0 and minusing this from the overall number of rows which have values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Above, I've figured out the answer to my own question by just simplifying exactly what I needed to do and it became very obvious:

`=COUNTA(S$2:S$74)-MATCH(2, 1/(S2:S$74=0), 1)`

This is basically finding the last position of 0 and minusing this from the overall number of rows which have values.

Comment: You are "array entering" that formula? Note that S2:S74 would have to fully populated for it to work correctly because when you use (S2:S$74=0) a truly blank cell in that range will also give TRUE

Comment: Yeah, I had to amend it to Count as i found that this didn't work in every instance. This works for me when I use S$2:s$500, to take account any new values being entered.

Comment: I have a formula in all the rows down to S500, so it does work ok.  The 1's and 0s are based on "attendances" for my football spreadsheet. It gives a 1 if that player played that week or a 0 if they didn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford a helper column then there is another very easy way to do this.

Enter this formula in B2 (or any other cell in row 2(Assuming you are using a header)) and copy it down.

```
=IF(AND(A2=0,A3=0),B1+1,1)
```

You can then pick up the maximum value from this range and if required hide the column.