# Calculate current streak in excel for multiple items

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

So I have a table with different names and a binary column for each, they are in order from oldest to newest, I need to calculate the current streak of 1's for each name. 
I've been building off the following 2 other questions, but neither of them quite fit my needs:

[calculate consecute streak in excel row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736286/calculate-consecute-streak-in-excel-row)

[How to count current streak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816078/how-to-count-current-streak)

As an example table:

[Sample Table (Can't embed pics yet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSU9k.jpg)

So far I got to being able to count the 1's for each Name chronologically with:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2,1)
```

But I'm still having trouble with the rest. I'm guessing it would be -MATCH() something but I can't quite figure it out.

What would be a formula to calculate this streak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using these formulas:

---

Streak:

```
=IF(F7=F6,(H7+I6)*H7,H7)
```

---

Is current (array formula):

```
 =IF(MAX(IF(F7=$F$7:$F$1663,$G$7:$G$1663))=G7,"TRUE","FALSE")
```

---

Personal Best (array formula):

```
=MAX(IF($F$7:$F$1663=L7,$I$7:$I$1663))
```

---

Current Streak (array formula):

```
=INDEX($F$7:$J$1663,MATCH(1,($F$7:$F$1663=L7)*($J$7:$J$1663="TRUE"),0),4)
```

---

F:H is a pivot table
[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHRHV.png)

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an index column
2. Use the Large function and Boolean logic for any filter criteria to find the last example of a break in the streak.
3. Subtract the current index number against the result. The difference is the streak.